# About diet for fatty liver, fruits, Fructose

Tags: diet, fatty-liver-disease

If one checks the media, there are lots of things who advertise the usage of fruits and etc for cleaning the liver. However, as I searched more, some say the fructose inside many fructose can be a danger for the liver (example: [here](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/liver-disease/nafld-nash/eating-diet-nutrition)). To the best of my knowledge, many fruits and vegetables have the fructose (more or less), then what the people do to have a healthy liver? I would like to know what is a very good diet for the fatty liver (at least knowing some great things for eating to help reversing the fatty liver)?

Edit- The idea behind this question is to clarify the hypothesis that some people say: "Fructose is not good for the liver and results fatty liver".

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98539/discussion-on-question-by-amin-about-diet-for-fatty-liver-fruits-fructose).